# syntaxError: Unespected end of input OK

Tags: ajax, opencart

fiz um upgrade do opencart da versão 1.5.x para a versão 2.0.1.1, tudo correu bem à excepção de que não consigo editar encomendas dos clientes nem alterar o estado da encomenda e notificar

Seguem os prints do que me está a contecer
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei várias soluções que encontrei, como adicionar a API,verificar na base de dados se o ID da API está correto

a Loja não está no modo de manutenção

Já alterei a funcção api(), como alguns sugerem, mas nada funciona

Comment: Abre o console do chrome apertando F12 e copia veja qual linha deu o erro.

Comment: DEscobri o problema, era nas traduções para português, alguma coisa não estava bem feita e faz com que exista uma incompatibilidade

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o Problema:

Era a tradução do opencart para PT_PT que não estava bem feita e fazia esse erro